# Passing a reference of a vector element to a threaded function

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, vector, reference

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

void foo(bool &check){

}

int main(){
    std::vector<bool> vec(1);
    std::thread T(foo, std::ref(vec[0]));
}
```

Unfortunately gcc throws an error:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:10:34: error: use of deleted function 'void std::ref(const _Tp&&) [with _Tp = std::_Bit_reference]'
  std::thread(foo, std::ref(vec[1]))
                                  ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/thread:39:0,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:453:10: note: declared here
     void ref(const _Tp&&) = delete;
```

However it works with a normal variable:

```
bool var;
std::thread(foo, std::ref(var));
```

I have no idea why I can't pass a reference to the vec element. Can someone explain why? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem is, that you use [`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool). `operator []` for `vector<bool>` returns not bool, but `std::vector<bool>::reference`, that is proxy class.
You can use something like:

```
bool value = vec[0];
std::thread T(foo, std::ref(value));
T.join();
vec[0] = value;
```

Comment: Is there no way to pass the reference to the vector element directly? With the workaround that you proposed, I would have to rewrite a half of my project.

Comment: @user3125731 don't use `vector<bool>`. Operator[] returns reference by copy, so, you cannot bind it to lvalue-reference. You can use move semantic probably, instead of reference.

Answer (score -1):

Another workaround (not tested)

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

void foo(vector& v){
  //here access v[0] and assign whatever value you'd like
  //ideally you could pass an index as well
  // if you want to access the Nth element
}

int main(){
    std::vector<bool> vec(1);
    std::thread T(foo, std::ref(vec));
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why this answer gets a downvote. Brilliant workaround.

Comment: often the simplest things are the best

Comment: OP is explicitly asking how to pass a vector component to a thread and not the whole vector for a reason.