# Returning all rows, or just the last one

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm writing up a bunch (~ a dozen) algorithms that iteratively process a vector in the following pattern:

```
ArrayXd prev;
ArrayXd curr;

prev = some_initial_vector();
for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    // do lots of stuff, many lines to compute curr
    // use lots of algorithm specific variables initialised above
    ...
    prev = curr;
}
return curr;
```

I would like to have a way of returning the entire history of the values of `curr` as well, as rows in an `ArrayXXd`.

I have tried solving this by writing two classes that exhibit a `curr` handle, one as an `ArrayXd &` the other as a `Block<ArrayXXd, 1, -1>`, but that failed as [it's not possible to reassign `Block`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38705842/how-do-you-change-a-block-in-eigen/).

What is a good way of solving this problem? Maybe I could store the `Block`s or the `ArrayXd`s themselves in a `std::vector` and then [convert that to an `ArrayXXd`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668485/eigen-and-stdvector/33669013#33669013) at the end.

**Edit:** Added sample input, output

```
struct NotAccumulator {
    typedef ArrayXd return_type;
    ArrayXd curr;
    ArrayXd prev;
    void record () {}
    return_type result() {
        return prev;
    }
};

struct RowAccumulator {
    typedef ArrayXXd return_type;
    ArrayXd curr;
    ArrayXd prev;
    RowAccumulator(const uint N) {
        history.reserve(N);
    }

    void record () {
        history.push_back(curr);
    }
    return_type result () {
        uint rows = history.size();
        uint cols = history[0].size();
        ArrayXXd result_matrix (rows, cols);
        for(uint i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            result_matrix.row(i) = Map<ArrayXd> (history[i].data(), cols);
        }
        return result_matrix;
    }

private:
    std::vector<ArrayXd> history;
};

template <typename Accumulator>
typename Accumulator::return_type add_one(const ArrayXd & start, const uint how_many_times, Accumulator & u) {
    u.prev = start;
    for (uint i = 0; i < how_many_times; ++i) {
        u.curr = 1 + u.prev;
        u.record();
        u.prev = u.curr;
    }
    return u.result();
}

ArrayXd start (3);
start << 1, 0, -1;
NotAccumulator notAccumulator;
RowAccumulator rowAccumulator (5);
cout << add_one(start, 5, notAccumulator) << endl;
// outputs 6 5 4
cout << add_one(start, 5, rowAccumulator) << endl;
// outputs 2 1 0\n 3 2 1\n ... 6 5 4
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample input and a desired output?

Comment: @FirstStep, updated it a bit. Let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: These are not "_sample_" inputs/outputs. These are just more codes. For example if my question is "_How to add two numbers?_". My input would be `1` and `3`. My output would be `4`. So, what structure you are processing and which part you need to keep track, save or `record`?

Comment: You may want to read this. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: As per your suggestions, I have added sample input/outputs

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the data copy as much as possible, you could allocate the `N`-row `ArrayXXd` in advance and avoid using `return`.

Buffers like `prev` and `curr` are unnecessary too. The following code also assumes the number of iterations `N` is known in advance.

```
void GenerateHistory(int N, ArrayXXd* result) {
    result.row(0) = gen_row0_without_prev();
    for(int curr=1; curr<N; curr++) {
        result.row(curr) = gen_row_with_prev_row(result.row(curr-1));
    }
}
```

You could call this function with

```
int N = 100;
int m = 20;
ArrayXXd history(N, m);
GenerateHistory(N, &history);
```

### EDIT

Let's put the copying issue aside. Here's an updated code that should fulfill the requirement according to your code sample.

```
ArrayXXd add_one(const ArrayXd& start, int num_iterations, bool acc) {
    if (acc) {
        ArrayXXd result = start;
        for(int i=0; i<num_iterations; i++) {
            result = result + 1;
        }
        return result;
    } else {
        ArrayXXd result(num_iterations, start.cols());
        result.row(0)=start+1;
        for(int i=1; i<num_iterations; i++) {
            result.row(i)=result.row(i-1);
        }
        return result;
    }
}

ArrayXd start (3);
start << 1, 0, -1;
bool acc = true;
cout << add_one(start, 5, !acc) << endl;
// outputs 6 5 4
cout << add_one(start, 5, acc) << endl;
// outputs 2 1 0\n 3 2 1\n ... 6 5 4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What you wrote doesn't seem to solve my problem as I would like to be able to return _either_ the whole history (as you do in your answer) _or_ just the last value. I have updated my question, hopefully it's clearer now

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but putting `result` as an input doesn't lead to less copying. A similar transformation is done by the compiler under the name _Return Value Optimisation_ automatically

Comment: You could use `ArrayXXd` with only 1 row for the NotAcc case. You don't need a separate return type. There will be a copy if you assign the return to a variable like `r=add_one(…)`

Comment: Instead of the `ArrayXXd*` you could use a `Eigen::Ref<ArrayXXd>`. No copy will occur.

Comment: @AviGinsburg both OK. Using pointers indicates the parameter is a output as suggested by some coding style guide.